# Using syntactically difficult strings as column names in a data frame

Tags: r, string, syntax, dataframe, names

I'm working with a data frame similar to the extract below:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("Some messy string to be used",222,0), 
                 B=c("Very important ? indicator from 2001", 888, 44),
                 C=c("001 This variable / makes no sense", 888, 44),
                 D=c("Geography", 1, 2))
```

I would like to use values in first row as column names, I'm using the code below:

```
names(df) <- make.names(df[1,])
```

Unfortunately, the syntax generates names in the format **Xn**, as illustrated below:

```
> names(df)
[1] "X3" "X3" "X1" "X3"
```

I understand that the utilised strings are to messy for `make.names` to be meaningfully converted. *How can I force R to use those messy string in a more efficient manner?* As a rule of thumb I would like to:

1. Keep figures (as they correspond to time)
2. Keep at least few first words from the text
3. Ensure that the names are unique
4. The whole solution have to be fairly generic as there is a lot of *rubbish* in the first row (usually empty spaces or special characters).

Comment: You may need `unlist` i.e. `make.names(unlist(df[1,]))`  The reason why you got `X1:X5` is `df` columns are `factor` and you got the numeric index after coercing, which was later converted by appending `X` with `make.unique`

Comment: @akrun, I would suggest that you post it as an answer as the suggested solution works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don’t need to use `make.names` at all — you can assign the strings *directly*. This works perfectly fine in R. You just need to backtick-quote the names when you try to use them as R names (e.g. after the `$` operator):

```
names(df) = unlist(df[1,])
df$`Some messy string to be used`
```

Comment: @KonradRudloph thanks it works. The slight nuisance is the need to add the **``** when using the name but it's not a major task.

Comment: @Konrad: of course you can also select the column by subsetting the data.frame without using `$`, e.g. `df[,"Some messy string to be used"]`

Answer (score 2):

use `stringsAsFactors = F` in data.frame which will create columns as char instead of factors. then make names on it.

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("Some messy string to be used",222,0), 
             B=c("Very important ? indicator from 2001", 888, 44),
             C=c("001 This variable / makes no sense", 888, 44),
             D=c("Geography", 1, 2),stringsAsFactors = F)
names(df) <- make.names(df[1,])
names(df)
```